# Trying to make a 2x2 rubik's cube solving algorithm , how do i find the solution path (DFS)?

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search, rubiks-cube

```
public class Cube extends Face{
    Face Up, Down, Left, Right, Back, Front;
    int numberOfTurns = 0;

    public Cube(){ //make Cube
        this.Up = new Face('W');
        this.Down = new Face('Y');
        this.Left = new Face('O');
        this.Right = new Face('R');
        this.Front = new Face('G');
        this.Back = new Face('B');
        }
    
    public Cube copy() {
        // Create a new Cube with copied faces
        Cube copyCube = new Cube();
        copyCube.Up = new Face(this.Up);
        copyCube.Down = new Face(this.Down);
        copyCube.Left = new Face(this.Left);
        copyCube.Right = new Face(this.Right);
        copyCube.Front = new Face(this.Front);
        copyCube.Back = new Face(this.Back);
        copyCube.numberOfTurns = this.numberOfTurns;

        return copyCube;
    }
     
    public boolean isGoal() {
        if ((isFaceAllColor(Back, 'B')==true) && (isFaceAllColor(Front, 'G')==true)&&(isFaceAllColor(Right, 'R')==true)
                &&(isFaceAllColor(Left, 'O')==true)&& (isFaceAllColor(Down, 'Y')==true)&&(isFaceAllColor(Up, 'W')==true))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
private boolean isFaceAllColor(Face face, char color) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                if (Character.valueOf(color).equals(Character.valueOf(face.getColor(i, j)))!=true) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
 public void move(String move) {
        switch (move) {
            case "F":
                F();
                break;
            case "U":
                U();
                break;
            case "R":
                R();
                break;
            case "B":
                B();
                break;
            case "L":
                L();
                break;
            case "D":
                D();
                break;
             case "Fi":
                 Fi();
                 break;
             case "Ui":
                 Ui();
                 break;
             case "Ri":
                 Ri();
                 break;
             case "Bi":
                 Bi();
                 break;
             case "Li":
                 Li();
                 break;
             case "Di":
                 Di();
                 break;
        }
    }
    char[] tempArray = new char[2];
    char Temp;

    private void TurnFaceClockwise(Face f) {
        char temp = f.face[0][0];
        f.face[0][0] = f.face[1][0];
        f.face[1][0] = f.face[1][1];
        f.face[1][1] = f.face[0][1];
        f.face[0][1] = temp;
    }


    public void R(){  // R
        TurnFaceClockwise(Right);
        tempArray[0] = Down.face[0][1]; //store right column
        tempArray[1] = Down.face[1][1];

        Down.face[0][1] = Back.face[1][0];
        Down.face[1][1] = Back.face[0][0];
        Back.face[1][0] = Up.face[0][1];
        Back.face[0][0] = Up.face[1][1];
        Up.face[0][1] = Front.face[0][1];
        Up.face[1][1] = Front.face[1][1];
        Front.face[0][1] = tempArray[0];
        Front.face[1][1] = tempArray[1];
    }

    public void L(){ // L
        TurnFaceClockwise(Left);
        tempArray[0] = Down.face[1][0]; //store left column
        tempArray[1] = Down.face[0][0];

        Down.face[0][0] = Front.face[0][0];
        Down.face[1][0] = Front.face[1][0];
        Front.face[0][0] = Up.face[0][0];
        Front.face[1][0] = Up.face[1][0];
        Up.face[1][0] = Back.face[0][1];
        Up.face[0][0] = Back.face[1][1];
        Back.face[0][1] = tempArray[0];
        Back.face[1][1] = tempArray[1];
    }

    public void U(){ // U
        TurnFaceClockwise(Up);
        tempArray[0] = Front.face[0][0]; //store Front Row
        tempArray[1] = Front.face[0][1];

        Front.face[0][0] = Right.face[0][0];
        Front.face[0][1] = Right.face[0][1];
        Right.face[0][0] = Back.face[0][0];
        Right.face[0][1] = Back.face[0][1];
        Back.face[0][0] = Left.face[0][0]; 
        Back.face[0][1] = Left.face[0][1];
        Left.face[0][0] = tempArray[0];
        Left.face[0][1] = tempArray[1];

    }

    public void D(){ // D
        TurnFaceClockwise(Down);
        tempArray[0] = Front.face[1][0]; //store Front bottom Row
        tempArray[1] = Front.face[1][1];

        Front.face[1][0] = Left.face[1][0];
        Front.face[1][1] = Left.face[1][1];
        Left.face[1][0] = Back.face[1][0];
        Left.face[1][1] = Back.face[1][1];
        Back.face[1][0] = Right.face[1][0]; 
        Back.face[1][1] = Right.face[1][1]; 
        Right.face[1][0] = tempArray[0];
        Right.face[1][1] = tempArray[1];
    }

    public void F(){ // F
        TurnFaceClockwise(Front);
        tempArray[0] = Up.face[1][0]; //store Up bottom Row
        tempArray[1] = Up.face[1][1];

        Up.face[1][0] = Left.face[1][1];
        Up.face[1][1] = Left.face[0][1];
        Left.face[0][1] = Down.face[0][0];
        Left.face[1][1] = Down.face[0][1];
        Down.face[0][0] = Right.face[1][0]; 
        Down.face[0][1] = Right.face[0][0]; 
        Right.face[0][0] = tempArray[0];
        Right.face[1][0] = tempArray[1];
    }

    public void B(){ // B
        TurnFaceClockwise(Back);
        tempArray[0] = Up.face[0][0]; //store Up Top Row
        tempArray[1] = Up.face[0][1];

        Up.face[0][0] = Right.face[0][1];
        Up.face[0][1] = Right.face[1][1];
        Right.face[0][1] = Down.face[1][1];
        Right.face[1][1] = Down.face[1][0];
        Down.face[1][1] = Left.face[1][0]; 
        Down.face[1][0] = Left.face[0][0]; 
        Left.face[0][0] = tempArray[1];
        Left.face[1][0] = tempArray[0];
    }
    public void Bi() {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            B();
        }
    }
    public void Ri() {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            R();
        }
    }
    public void Ui() {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            U();
        }
    }
    public void Li() {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            L();
        }
    }
    public void Di() {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            D();
        }
    }
    public void Fi() {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            F();
        }
    }
   
}
public class Face {

    char[][] face; //face
    
    public Face(){ //make empty face
        face = new char[2][2];
    }
    
    public Face(char s){ //make face with color
        face = new char[2][2];
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
                face[i][j] = s;
            }
        }   
    }
    public Face(Face other) {
        // Copy the face array
        this.face = Arrays.copyOf(other.face, other.face.length);
    }
    
    public char getColor(int x, int y){
        return face[x][y];
    }
}

public class CubeSolver {
    private static Set<Cube> visitedStates = new HashSet<>();
    private static StringBuilder solutionSteps = new StringBuilder();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cube b=new Cube();
        b.Ui();
      
        CubeSolver.solveDFShelper(b, 10); // Set the desired depth limit for the search
    }
    
    public static void solveDFShelper(Cube cube, int maxDepth) {
        String[] moves = {"F", "U", "L", "R", "D", "B", "Li", "Ui", "Bi", "Di", "Ri", "Fi"};
        visitedStates.clear();
        solutionSteps.setLength(0);
        boolean solutionFound = dfs(cube, maxDepth, moves); // Use the maxDepth parameter here
        if (solutionFound) {
            System.out.println("Solution found. Steps: " + solutionSteps.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No solution found.");
        }
    }


    public static boolean dfs(Cube cube, int depthLimit, String[] moves) {
        if (cube.isGoal()) {
            return true;  // Found a solution
        }
        if (depthLimit == 0) {
            return false;  // Reached depth limit without finding a solution
        }

        for (String move : moves) {
            Cube newCube = cube.copy();
            newCube.move(move);
            //System.out.println(move + " :" + newCube.getCubeColorsAsString());
            if (!visitedStates.contains(newCube)) {
                visitedStates.add(newCube);
                solutionSteps.append(move);  // Append the entire move at once
                if (dfs(newCube, depthLimit - 1, moves)) {
                    return true;  // Solution found
                }
                solutionSteps.setLength(solutionSteps.length() - move.length());  // Backtrack
                visitedStates.remove(newCube);  // Backtrack
            }
        }

        return false;  // No solution found at this depth
    }
```

the moves i implemented work fine ,and i know that because if i try to solve it while printing the cube after every move , it checks out . but for some reason the solution path that the code returns is not right , if i try to do the solution path on the same cube withy the same scramble it gets scrambled even more . if anyone sees the problem please tell me.

Comment: I ran your code on my own `Cube` implementation, and it returned "FFFFU", which is a correct solution for the "scrambled" cube you provided in `main`. If you get the same result, then please adapt your `main` so that the problem is reproduced. If you get a different result, then the problem is in your `Cube` implementation.

Comment: BTW to avoid the 4 repetitions at start like in `FFFF`, add the initial cube to the `visitedSteps`; and I agree with previous comment, **posted** code should work, maybe something wrong with `Cude` (`hashCode()`, `isGoal()`, `copy()`, ...) - usually it is better to include a [mre]

Comment: im exhausted , btw my result path is [F, F, F, Di, Fi, Fi, F, Ui, L, B] if that helps in anyway, if possible id like to chat with anyone of you, so i can send him my cube implementation maybe he can help me , id be grateful .or maybe i should edit my post and put the cube implementation i don't know I'm new here

Comment: Yes, just add the Cube implementation  in your question. Limit it to only the methods/fields that are actually needed to make the above code run.

Comment: @trincot added every thing needed, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- In the `Face(Face other)` constructor, you're not creating a `face` field that is completely independent from the `other.face` data. `Arrays.copyOf` makes a *shallow* copy, and so the two inner arrays are now *shared* by the two `Face` instances. This leads to havoc when you start making moves on a cube -- it will impact other instance(s) that are in your visited map. Fix that constructor to something like this:

  ```
  public Face(Face other) {
      face = new char[][] {
          Arrays.copyOf(other.face[0], 2),
          Arrays.copyOf(other.face[1], 2)
      };
  }
  ```
- The condition `visitedStates.contains(newCube)` will never be true, as `newCube` is a new object reference, and you haven't overridden the default `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Here are possible implementations:

  In `Cube`:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
      if (!(other instanceof Cube)) return false;
      Cube otherCube = (Cube) other;
      return  Up.equals(otherCube.Up) &&
              Down.equals(otherCube.Down) &&
              Left.equals(otherCube.Left) &&
              Right.equals(otherCube.Right) &&
              Back.equals(otherCube.Back) &&
              Front.equals(otherCube.Front);
      }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(Up, Down, Left, Right, Back, Front);
  }
  ```

  And in `Face`:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
      return other instanceof Face && Arrays.deepEquals(face, ((Face) other).face);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return Arrays.deepHashCode(face);
  }
  ```

With these two problems fixed, your code will output this:

```
Solution found. Steps: FFFFU
```

This is the expected output of your `dfs` implementation.

### Other comments

You could improve on the `dfs` algorithm, by marking the starting position also as visited. Then you will not have four of the same moves at the start of the solution.

Be aware that your `isGoal` method does not consider a cube solved when it just happens to be oriented differently, but would actually be considered solved. The same is true for the `hashCode` and `equals` implementations I provided: they don't consider two cubes equal when one can be obtained from the other by just changing the orientation of the whole cube. There are 24 different ways a cube can be oriented.

For solving cubes that are more scrambled than the one you created in your `main` code, DFS might not be the ideal search algorithm. You might want to have the solver target some sub-targets, such as one corner that is placed correctly, then two, then three, ...etc.

Comment: i just have a quick question , my code seems to stop working(its so slow)  when i start my cube scrambled with more than 6 moves , is that part of your comment that dfs is a bad algorithm ? other than that it works fast and gives the right path

Comment: The depth first algorithm may have to look through the whole search tree, which widens with approx 10 cubes at every level, i.e in the order of a million when at depth 6.  And generating a cube costs time, each cube creating 6 Face objects, and each of those creating two arrays...etc